# node require all or only specific

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I was wondering if it is better to require only the specific propertie we want or the entire object.

Exemple:

Here is my helper file

```
'use strict';

/**
 * getCallback
 * return a function used to make callback
 * @param {callback} callback - the callback function
 * @returns {Function}
 */
function getCallback(callback) {
    let cb = (typeof callback === 'function')
        ? callback
        : function() {};

    return cb;
}

/**
 * Random Number function
 * This function give a random number min and max
 * @param {number} [min=0] - min number you can get
 * @param {number} [max=1] - max number you can get
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function randomNumber(min, max) {
    let _min = (min) ? parseInt(min) : 0;
    let _max = (max) ? parseInt(max) : 1;

    return Math.floor((Math.random() * _max) + _min);
}

/**
 * Random String function
 * This function give a random string with the specified length
 * @param {number} length - length of the string
 * @param {string} chars - char you want to put in your random string
 * @returns {String}
 */
function randomString(length, chars) {

    let text = '';
    chars = (chars) ? chars : 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
    }

    return text;
}

exports.getCallback = getCallback;
exports.randomNumber = randomNumber;
exports.randomString = randomString;
```

And here an other file that needs two of this helper function

is it better to do this

```
'use strict';

const util = require('./helpers/util.helper');

console.log(util.randomNumber(0, 10));
console.log(util.randomString(10));
```

Or this

```
'use strict';

const randomNumber = require('./helpers/util.helper').randomNumber;
const randomString = require('./helpers/util.helper').randomString;

console.log(randomNumber(0, 10));
console.log(randomString(10));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd likely want to require the whole file. Splitting everything up would make it harder if you end up changing the names or functionality within the util file. I guess this is a bit personal preference, but in the latter option you are a bit more dependent on the insides of the util. The pieces of code would be pretty tightly coupled. This also follows the OOP way of having a single object, which exposes several methods for use as needed.

For example, in the latter option, you would have to change the method name in three places instead of the one in the first option.

See more about coupling here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)